# deserialize protostuff byte array with javascript

Tags: javascript, java, protostuff

I used [protostuff](http://www.protostuff.io/) to transform to byte array a json input i have. The code in java is:

```
LinkedBuffer buffer = LinkedBuffer.allocate(1024);
Schema<String> orderSchema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(String.class);
int i = 1 ;
for(String p:poligonsStr) {               
    buffer.clear();
    byteslist.add(ProtostuffIOUtil.toByteArray(p, orderSchema, buffer));
}
```

The problem is I don't know the algorithm that is used and how I can decode with the JavaScript client (Node.js). Also I saw there is a very good algorithm called Smile implemented for protostuff in project com.dyuproject.protostuff  but I would like to know how to get schema with that library- I didn't manage that yet.

I would like to know what's the best to use: `ProtostuffIOUtil` or `SmileIOUtil`?
And how to use? And how to decode with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*protostuff* binary encoding is different from *protobuf*, and as far as I know there is no JavaScript library to decode protostuff-encoded data at the moment.

*smile* is not supported by web browsers out of the box, but there are libraries that can decode it.

As for me, there are two optiomal ways how you can encode data on server using Protostuff library, and decode it using JavaScript on client side:

1. Use *protobuf* encoding, it is good if size of encoded data is important. On server side, you should use `ProtobufIOUtil` to serialize your data to protobuf binary format. On client side, you can use https://github.com/dcodeIO/ProtoBuf.js/ to decode binary data from server.
2. Use *JSON* encoding, it is native format for JavaScript and usually it will be parsed faster than binary protobuf-encoded data. On server side, you should use `JsonIOUtil` (from protostuff-json module) to serialize your data to JSON text format. On client side, it is supported out of the box.

Here is an example how to serialize your POJO into protobuf binary using Protostuff: [HelloService.java](https://github.com/protostuff/protostuff-examples/blob/master/hello-world/src/main/java/io/protostuff/examples/HelloService.java#L33)

Comment: Thanks! I want to try to encode with protostuff protobuf encoding and decode on client with ProtoBuf.js...I have the code :
        byte[] bytes={};
        LinkedBuffer buffer = LinkedBuffer.allocate();
        Schema<Level> orderSchema = RuntimeSchema.getSchema(Level.class);
        int i = 0 ;
         for (Level p : poligons) {             
                buffer.clear();              
                bytes = ProtobufIOUtil.toByteArray(p, orderSchema, buffer);
                i++;
            }  
        return bytes.toString();